# Multi Image Upload causes app to crash saying too many open files

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I am using `https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker` in my project so that the user can select multiple images.

Following is my code to upload multiple images to Firebase Storage

```
StorageReference _storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref();

          await Future.wait(userSelectImages.map((Asset asset) async {
            ByteData byteData = await asset.getByteData(quality: 50);
            List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();


            StorageUploadTask _uploadTask =
                _storageReference.child("$HEALTH_LOG/${asset.name}").putData(imageData);

            final StreamSubscription<StorageTaskEvent> _streamSubscription =
                _uploadTask.events.listen((event) {
              double percent = event != null
                  ? event.snapshot.bytesTransferred /
                      event.snapshot.totalByteCount
                  : 0;
            });


            uploadUrls
                .add(await (await _uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL());
            await _streamSubscription.cancel();
```

But I get a crash saying `Too many open files` and `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY`

The code works fine when I select one or two images, but if select 7 to 8 images I get the crash

**Edit 2**
Alright after debugging more I got to know the real issue. There is no error or bug in the way I am uploading an image to `firebase` storage. The main issue is to display those user-selected images.

Suppose the user picks multiple images. Now I want to preview those images before the user can upload them to firebase. So I am displaying those images in `GridView.Builder` which causes the out of memory issue. I have found a bug on Flutter repo regarding this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21571

So my code for displaying images in GridView is as follows

```
return GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3, childAspectRatio: 1),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: AssetThumb(
                      asset: patientHealthLogsBloc.resultAssetValue[index],
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width ~/ 3,
                      height: 100,
                      quality: 30,

                    ),

                  );
                },
                itemCount: patientHealthLogsBloc?.resultAssetValue?.length ?? 0,
              );
```

If I comment on the above code of displaying previews then images are uploaded properly but displaying those images causes out of memory error. I even tested on the iPad which causes the same issue.

Comment: what is the value of `userSelectImages.length`?

Comment: hmm, do you have to use `Future.wait` and wait for all of them?

Comment: i would try to do that one by one by using `Future.forEach` - the docs say: *"Calls action with each element in elements in order. If the call to action returns a Future<T>, the iteration waits until the future is completed before continuing with the next element."*

Comment: and are you sure that upload is done one by one? does it mean that you got error in first upload?

Comment: @pskink Check my question again i have found the root cause of error but dont know to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the real root cause of the issue was that the widget was wrapped in a stream builder which caused it to keep rebuilding it again and again even  if data did not changed